# Separating two separate bits of information in parenthesis

Tags: grammar, scientific-publishing

I have this excerpt of text from a scientific paper:

> ... such as mitochondrial DNA (mtDNA; maternally inherited) or non-recombining regions of Y-chromosomal DNA (paternally inherited), ...

Where I want to specify the inheritance of the two types of DNA I mention, but I also need to clarify the abbreviation of mitochondrial DNA to mtDNA as it is it's first mention within the text.

Is there a standard, grammatically correct way of separating 'mtDNA' and 'maternally inherited' in the parenthesis? I have tentatively settled on:

> (mtDNA; maternally inherited)

But I'm not sure if this (or indeed any other way) would be preferred:

> (mtDNA, maternally inherited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is quite clear the way you have phrased it, but if you want to skip the two items in one parenthesis, you can simply reword it as

> ... such as the maternally inherited mitochondrial DNA (mtDNA) or the paternally inherited non-recombining regions of Y-chromosomal DNA, ...

maybe making its own parenthetical blocks with em dashes

> ... such as the —maternally inherited— mitochondrial DNA (mtDNA) or the —paternally inherited— non-recombining regions of Y-chromosomal DNA, ...